# Pick 4 values to return a value from other column

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a scenario that the users have to pick 4 values from each dropdown. If all of those values match with what is in database/table (more than 100 rows). It will return a result on a textbox. Please see the sketch below, I am using VB. Thank you for your help.

> product|col1|col2|col3|col4
>
> apple  |1   |2   |3   |4
>
> grape  |2   |4   |4   |6
>
> orange |1   |3   |5   |7

Pick from dropdown

> dropdown1: 1
>
> dropdown2: 2
>
> dropdown3: 3
>
> dropdown4: 4
>
> textbox: apple.

Comment: I have tried with if as user7777 mentioned. However, this only works with specific data. Table has more than 100 records. It would be pain, if I use every single if. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mych said that data is in your database so you just need to query into your database and find the product that matches the different columns.

There are many ways in vb.net to grab info from your database.
Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
Using conn as New SqlConnection("ConnectionStringToDatabase")
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd as New SqlCommand("your_query", conn)
       Dim reader as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
       If reader.HasRows Then
           reader.Read
           textbox1.Text = reader("product")
       End If
       reader.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Where the following is imported:
    System.Data.SqlClient

and your query is similar too what Mych suggested:

```
"Select Distinct product from MyDataTable Where Col1 = " & dropdown1.SelectedValue &
" AND Col2 = " & dropdown2.SelectedValue & " AND Col3 =" & dropdown3.SelectedValue &
" AND Col4 =" & dropdown4.SelectedValue
```

Comment: This is a good way to me. Unfortunately, my place is using old school style. They are using Access Database and create a form within Access. Sorry for not mention in the beginning.

Comment: You have to do the research into connecting to an Access database. You now know how to do it, now you just need the right syntax. If you're having trouble still, update your question with code and your efforts. Then I can help you more.

Comment: D query is working very well. I have a combobox5 to display final values after picking from other 4 cbboxes. I place d query in combobox5's Property\Row Source. It does works if we manually input correct 4 different values from 4 columns. However, it prompt a window to take input from user, instead of getting values from other comboboxes. I use query:

SELECT product FROM producttbl WHERE col1 = cbo1.SelectedValue AND col2= Cbo2.SelectedValue AND col3= Cbo3.SelectedValue AND col4= Cbo4.SelectedValue;

How do I get d values from other cbboxes instead of prompt a window for parameter input?

Comment: what do you mean it prompts? Did you use quotes and & like the above query does? And please use 'the' instead of 'd' so that it is easier to read.

Comment: I put that query into row source and run the application. When user click on combobox, it pops up a small window to ask for Enter Parameter Value". I don't use & because the row source doesn't take &. This does works if user manually input values into "Enter Parameter Value" textbox. However, I want user to pick values from combobox instead of manually typing into textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You say the data is in a database....

Make a Select Statement to find the row...

```
Select from MyDataTable Product Where Col1 = dropdown1.SelectedValue 
AndAlso Col2 = dropdown2.SelectedValue AndAlso Col3 = dropdown3.SelectedValue 
AndAlso Col4 = dropdown4.SelectedValue
```